# Dropzone.js thumbnail event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am using the JQuery framework "Dropzone.js" to upload files on server.

I want to do some stuff when the thumbnail is displaying. The other things are working without issue. The DOM is displaying before the javascript call.

I tried to initiate the thumbnail in two ways, according to [Dropzone.js documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events) :

```
  var dz = new Dropzone(
   'div#'+id,
    {
    init: function() {
       this.on("thumbnail", function(file) {console.log("thumbnail") });
    },
...
  }
```

and :

```
var dz =  new Dropzone(...);
dz.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
    console.log("thumbnail")
  });
```

And nothing is displaying in my browser console when I drop a file in the dropzone. The most weird behaviour is that when I write the same things with the event `addedfile` (`dz.on("addedfile", ...` or in the init parameter), I have the correct behaviour : I have something written in the console when a file is added.

Note that I want to modify dynamically the thumbnail when it is created, and this is why I can't use other event.

I use a custom `previewTemplate` in my Dropzone object; I don't think that cause the issue, but in the doubt I post what I wrote for this parameter too:

```
previewTemplate : '<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview ">'
 + '<div class="dz-details">'
   + '<div class="dz-cancel" title="Supprimer">X</div>'
   + '<div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>'
   + '<div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>'
 + '</div>'
 + '<div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span><span class="dz-upload-text" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>'
 + '<div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>'
+ '</div>',
```

If someone has an idea of what is happening and how can I resolve it, I thank a lot !

**Edit after comments**

Ok, then, thanks for all for your comments. I think I know where I misunderstood; and reading more carefully the doc, that was the point :

> They do stuff like: create a new HTML element, add the  element when provided with image data (with the thumbnail event),

This event is only fired when we want to display an image in the thumbnail; but what I am doing is a thumbnail without image (just the name of the file and the size). And that's right that when I add the `createImageThumbnails` flag and the `<img data-dz-thumbnail />` in the template, the event is triggered when I add an image file in the drop zone.

So, my new question is: how to display an event when a free-image thumbnail is created ? I thought in using the `uploadprogress` event but it is not triggered when the file is not sent (for example, when activating a max file size limit).

Comment: did you activate createImageThumbnails flag?  http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-createImageThumbnails

Comment: and your `previewTemplate` misses the `<img data-dz-thumbnail />` section.

Comment: try this one, dz.emit("thumbnail", function(file) { console.log("thumbnail")});

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tpaksu/ufwdfnwa/ here it is working?

Comment: Please, ahve a look on the edited post

Comment: @CasperSL : that is just triggering "manually" the event, but I want it to be fired automatically when creating the thmbnail

Comment: @TahaPaksu : the jsfiddle displayed has only a basic dropzone

Comment: Yes but triggering the on("thumbnail") event with the second example of yours, and the parameters used within that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your using it in the right way. I would try the following approach:

```
var dz =  new Dropzone(...);

Dropzone.options.dz = {
 init: function() {
    this.on("thumbnail", function(file) { console.log("thumbnail") });
  }
};
```

If the event does what you expect it to do is a different matter.

Comment: I tried and have the same result; I think that thumbnail event is currently only fired when the dropped file is a picture, and the option `createImageThumbnails` is true. Probably there is no event for the creation of a free-image thumbnail; but thanks for trying !